# Date difference with VBA InputBox in "Years" "Months" "Days" format

Tags: vba, excel

I have used the following VBA code to calculate age on a specific date.
With this VBA code i can only get difference only in years.

How can I get the age in format of **"XX Years, YY Months, ZZ Days"**

```
    Sub ageCalculator()

    Sheet2.Select
    Range("a2").Select
    Dim w As Date
    Dim x As Date
    w = InputBox("Enter Date of Birth")
    x = InputBox("Enter <age on> date")
    Range("a2").Value = DateDiff("yyyy", w, x) & "Years"
    End Sub
```

If I add `& DateDiff("yyyymm", w, x) & "Months" & DateDiff("mmdd", w, x) & "Days"` it says Run-time error "5":
How can I get age or difference of two dates as above mentioned formate?

Comment: Don't try to combine days with months or months with years. Do each separately. So you'll have three DateDiff functions.

Comment: I tried, but it results full difference in Months or days , for example if we enter 01//01/2015 in date of birth, in first function, it results 1 Years, but in second function it results 24 months and so on at third on days(dd). But in need the result as <1 Years 0 Months 0 Days.> How can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try playing with something like this

```
Dim a As Date     ' Date of birth
Dim b As Date     ' Age on date
Dim c As Date     ' Temp date
Dim d As Date     ' temp date

a = DateSerial(1970, 10, 1)
b = DateSerial(2016, 1, 1)

Dim intYears As Integer
intYears = DateDiff("yyyy", a, b) - IIf(Month(b) < Month(a), 1, 0)

Dim intMonths As Integer
c = DateAdd("yyyy", intYears, a)
intMonths = DateDiff("m", c, b)- IIf(day(b) < day(a), 1, 0)

Dim intDays As Integer
d = DateAdd("m", intMonths, c)
intDays = DateDiff("d", d, b)
```

Comment: `a = DateSerial(1976, 10, 1) ` and `b = DateSerial(2016, 12, 1)` gives age as 39 but should be `40`. Also, `a = DateSerial(1976, 10, 16) ` with same `b` gives a negative `intDays`

Comment: I knew there was an easier way then I was trying to solve it :) ...   Take out the -1 in `intYears` formula and it works perfect for all my testing.

Comment: `a = DateSerial(1976, 9, 1)` and `b = DateSerial(2016, 6, 1)` gives age as 40 when should be 39. To get age right you must compare the dates to see which is older and then -1 accordingly...

Comment: intYears = DateDiff("yyyy", a, b) - IIf(Month(b) < Month(a), 1, 0) as I said, have a play with.... :)

Comment: Ok. But same logic applies to `intMonths`. You need to account for the day of the month to know whether to `-1` or not...

Comment: `a = DateSerial(1976, 8, 15)` and `b = DateSerial(2016, 3, 14)` gives `39 years 6 months 28 days` but should be 30 days?

Comment: 16/2 to 14/3 =28?  Just checked 15/2 is counted in month's days, then on calendar, 28 days, not 29 until 28th day's elapsed, ie. end of day b.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following:

```
Sub ageCalculator()
    Dim age As Integer, dob As Date, dt As Date

    dob = InputBox("Enter Date of Birth")
    dt = InputBox("Enter <age on> date")

    years = IIf(dt > DateSerial(Year(dt), Month(dob), Day(dob)), DateDiff("yyyy", dob, dt), DateDiff("yyyy", dob, dt) - 1)
    months = IIf(Day(dt) > Day(dob), Abs(Month(dob) - Month(dt)), Abs(Month(dob) - Month(dt)) - 1)
    days = IIf(Day(dt) > Day(dob), Day(dt) - Day(dob), (Day(DateSerial(Year(dob), Month(dob) + 1, 1) - 1) - Day(dob)) + Day(dt))

    Debug.Print years & "years " & months & "months" & days & "days"
End Sub
```